# Trimming the contents of a dictionary in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have an Excel formula that finds the **Nth to last word** in a cell and outputs it. However, now I use a VBA macro to output badly ordered data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 in a more formatted form.

What I am trying to do now is to modify the contents of the data structure that I store the data in before it gets copied to the 2nd sheet. In the 2nd sheet I would like to only have specific things (like 2nd/3rd to last word or only the numbers). The data structure that is being used is dictionary.

I know the basic way to do this in VBA is:

```
Split(Sheets("reportsheet").Range("A1").Value, " ")(wordNumber - 1)
```

However, I really am lost on how to apply this in my case. The VBA code is as follows:

```
Sub findData()

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet

    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set datasheet = Sheet1
    Set reportsheet = Sheet2

    Dim chNum As String 'Ticket number
    Dim chSub As String 'Change subject
    Dim rptNum As String 'analysis number
    Dim ChangeNumbers As New Dictionary 'dictionary that holds all of the info (ticket number, change subject, analysis number and details)

    Dim dictKey1 As Variant
    Dim dictKey2 As Variant
    Dim dictKey3 As Variant
    Dim dictKey4 As Variant

    Dim formula1 As String
    Dim formula2 As String

    reportsheet.Range("A1:H200").ClearContents
    finalrow1 = datasheet.Cells(datasheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop that finds the required pieces of text from the data-sheet
    For i = 1 To finalrow1
        'Basic info in column A
        SearchString = datasheet.Range("A" & i)

        If InStr(1, SearchString, "Change number") Then
            chNum = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)

            ChangeNumbers.Add chNum, New Dictionary 'For ticket numbers
        ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "Change subject") Then
            chSub = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Add chSub, New Dictionary 'For change subjects
        ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "Report-") Then
            rptNum = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Add rptNum, New Dictionary 'For analysis

            'Loop for the details (requirements, tech.specs, impl. and testing)
            j = 0
            'Verifies that the details belong to the current report
            'String checks are included after locating a report to maintain a connection between the report and its details
            Do While IsEmpty(datasheet.Cells(i + j, 1)) Or datasheet.Cells(i + j, 1) = rptNum
                If InStr(1, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2), "Priority") Then
                    ' The 4 after ".Add" is the column number for this detail in sheet2
                    ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 4, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #1
                ElseIf InStr(1, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2), "Workload") Then
                    ' The 5 after ".Add" is the column number for this detail in sheet2
                    ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 5, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #2
                ElseIf InStr(1, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2), "Deadline") Then
                    ' The 6 after ".Add" is the column number for this detail in sheet2
                    ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 6, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #3
                End If

                j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next i

    i = 1
    For Each dictKey1 In ChangeNumbers.Keys
        reportsheet.Cells(i, 1) = dictKey1 'Change Ticket Number

        If ChangeNumbers.Item(dictKey1).Count > 0 Then
            For Each dictKey2 In ChangeNumbers.Item(dictKey1).Keys
                reportsheet.Cells(i, 2) = dictKey2 'Change Subject; assuming in column B on same row as Change Number

                If ChangeNumbers.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Count > 0 Then
                    For Each dictKey3 In ChangeNumbers.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Keys 'Analysis number
                        reportsheet.Cells(i, 3) = dictKey3
                        'reportsheet.Cells(i, 2) = dictKey2 'Uncomment if you want change subject in every row w/ matching report

                        For Each dictKey4 In ChangeNumbers.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Keys
                            reportsheet.Cells(i, dictKey4) = ChangeNumbers.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Item(dictKey4)
                        Next dictKey4
                        i = i + 1 'moves to new row for new report (or next change number)
                    Next dictKey3
                Else
                    i = i + 1 'no reports, so moves down to prevent overwriting change number
                End If
            Next dictKey2
        Else
            i = i + 1 'no change subject, so moves down to prevent overwriting change number
        End If
    Next dictKey1


End Sub
```

I find the documentation on VBA functions to be extremely hard to follow. I couldn't find an answer on how to apply this in practice. I tried to change everything after it was stored in the dictionary but this didn't seem to work. All my efforts have either resulted in the loop stopping or errors.

Someone can give me tips on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

There are three options:

1. Split the string before storing it in the dictionary
2. Edit the dictionary contents
3. Split the strings as they're extracted from the dictionary

For most code, I would believe that using option 1) would make the most sense. Mostly because dictionaries may get used multiple times. Also, this method allows for if the string you want to edit works as a key.

Depending on the dictionary structure, option 2) could be the simplest, or the most complicated. (With your nested dictionaries -- and possibly different rules for which word to save -- , this would probably be more complicated). However, if you wanted to go this method, be aware that you would have to overwrite an old item with the new one (and if you're changing key values, you'll only be adding keys -- not overwriting them)

If you're only extracting the values from a dictionary once, it may be simplest to edit the string right before using it where desired.

---

I believe for your code, you may wish to make the edit before storing the value(s) in the dictionary.

Which, I believe, would be primarily in this section of your code:

```
For i = 1 To finalrow1
        'Basic info in column A
        SearchString = datasheet.Range("A" & i)

        If InStr(1, SearchString, "Change number") Then
            chNum = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)

            ChangeNumbers.Add chNum, New Dictionary 'For ticket numbers
        ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "Change subject") Then
            chSub = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Add chSub, New Dictionary 'For change subjects
        ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "Report-") Then
            rptNum = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Add rptNum, New Dictionary 'For analysis

            'Loop for the details (requirements, tech.specs, impl. and testing)
            j = 0
            'Verifies that the details belong to the current report
            'String checks are included after locating a report to maintain a connection between the report and its details
            Do While IsEmpty(datasheet.Cells(i + j, 1)) Or datasheet.Cells(i + j, 1) = rptNum
                If InStr(1, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2), "Priority") Then
                    ' The 4 after ".Add" is the column number for this detail in sheet2
                    ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 4, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #1
                ElseIf InStr(1, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2), "Workload") Then
                    ' The 5 after ".Add" is the column number for this detail in sheet2
                    ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 5, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #2
                ElseIf InStr(1, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2), "Deadline") Then
                    ' The 6 after ".Add" is the column number for this detail in sheet2
                    ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 6, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #3
                End If

                j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next i
```

---

The split-line example you provided:

```
Split(Sheets("reportsheet").Range("A1").Value, " ")(wordNumber - 1)
```

has a `wordNumber` variable which I don't see anywhere in your existing code; so I will assume it's a pseudo (place-holder) variable, for now.

---

I would probably attempt to add the splitting like so:

Instead of

```
chNum = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
```

add the split to make it

```
chNum = Split(datasheet.Cells(i, 1)," ")(wordNumber - 1)
```

Instead of

```
ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 4, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #1
```

add the split to make it

```
ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 4, Split(datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2)," ")(wordNumber - 1) ' the detail #1
```

And so on, through the other applicable sections of code.

---

Note for the first example above, if you added the split here:

```
ChangeNumbers.Add chNum, New Dictionary 'For ticket numbers
```

-->

```
ChangeNumbers.Add Split(chNum," ")(wordNumber - 1), New Dictionary 'For ticket numbers
```

I believe you would cause errors, as a line such as:

```
ChangeNumbers.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(rptNum).Add 4, datasheet.Cells(i + j, 2) ' the detail #1
```

would no longer reference a valid key in the `ChangeNumbers` dictionary (`chNum` would no longer be equal to the key assigned here, `ChangeNumbers.Add Split(chNum," ")(wordNumber - 1), New Dictionary 'For ticket numbers` (key --> `Split(chNum," ")(wordNumber - 1)`)